# How to interact with black dead window in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Periodically i'm get these black windows on my desktop:

[image]

Please, tell me, how to remove them without computer reboot?

P.S. I'm close the viber and black window dissapear. But why it's popup is black?

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl-alt-F3 to switch to a terminal login window. Log in and run "ps -ax | grep gdm3" and then kill the process running /usr/sbin/gdm3.  Then type ctrl-alt-F2 to return to the gdm login screen. If you can't get a terminal window, try logging in over ssh from another machine and perform the same steps.   You will need to login in again, but you will not have to reboot.

Preserving the existing session may or may not be possible.  You can try killing screensavers and other apps that take over the full screen, but there's no guarantees it will work.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Sorry, i'm can't repeat situation. I'm add reaction as soon as get the same bug on my desktop.